# Writing Arrays to a Tab Delimited Text File

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv

I apologize if this question is a duplicate; but none of the other posts have been of much use to me as of yet. I would like to output the arrays t and x from the following code into a text file with two columns, t being the first and x being the second, with a tab delimiter. The code I have so far looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

tt = 10.0  #total time 
dt = 1.0   #time step
n = int(tt/dt) #number of iteration steps

t = [0.0]*n #initialize an array of times, initially zero and with length n
x = [0.0]*n #initialize x arry

for i in range(n-1):
    x[i] = np.sin(4.0*t)
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt

with open('output.txt', 'a') as output:
    for a, am in zip(t, x):
        output.write("{}\t{}".format(a, am))
```

I have an empty text file named 'output', but nothing is getting written to it, much less two tab-delimited columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the placeholders in the format string.

```
output.write("{}\t{}".format(a, am))
```

should read

```
output.write("{0}\t{1}".format(a, am))
```